# how to move a file in desktop in a directory?

Tags: php, mv

I want to move a `.php` file named `My Form.php` which I have saved on my Desktop before to `\var\www`.

When I use: `sudo mv My Form.php www` in terminal, it says there is no such file `My.php` and `Form.php`.

Comment: try using ls to view files and pwd to view in which directory you're performing operation

Comment: `\var\www` is wrong in Unix/Linux. A correct path is `/var/www`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the filename inside `""` doublequotes because your file has a space in his name and so it's seen as 2 separate file from the shell. You need either to issue `sudo mv "My Form.php" /var/www` or `sudo mv My\ Form.php /var/www` the backslash `\` before the space is an escape character.
Note that in Ubuntu (and -in general- under Linux) file path are described using `/` and not `\`

Comment: I'm assuming you are going to issue the command from the same folder `"My Form.php"` is in, otherwise you have to prefix the filename with the full path to the file `.php`

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and run this commnd:

```
sudo mv ~/Desktop/My\ Form.php /var/www
```

Here's what you did wrong:

> I use: sudo mv My Form.php www in terminal

- `sudo mv My Form.php`

  `mv` interprets there are two files: `My` and `Form.php`, therefore, the backslash before the space. Also double quotes can be used (`sudo mv "~/Desktop/My Form.php" /var/www`).
- `www`

  That doesn't help you at all; your target is `/var/www`